# How to change python numpy pointer type like C++?

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array, whose `shape` is (2,), and `dtype` is `np.int64`, say,

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.empty((2,), dtype=np.int64)
```

Now, I'd like to use the same memory zone, but change its `dtype` to `np.int32`. If it is C++, I can write

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;
vector<int64_t> a(2);
int32_t* b = reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(a.data());
```

In fact, I can write in python this way

```py
b = np.array(a, copy=False)
b.dtype = np.int32
```

I can do what I want in this way. But, if I use `mypy` to check my code, `mypy` will say `error: Property "dtype" defined in "ndarray" is read-only  [misc]`. I'd like to know if there is any way more appropriately to do what I want in numpy?

Comment: You could use `np.view` which will return a numpy array with the same underlying buffer.

Comment: Read the `ndarray.dtype` docs, especialy the warning about future changes. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dtype.html.  The ability to set array attributes directly is something of a legacy feature, that numpy is moving away from.  I think using methods like `view` gives you and numpy more protection from bad moves.

Comment: what's the purpose of this exercsize?  `a` is (2,) with unknown values. `a.astype(np.int32)` would still be (2,).  `a.view(np.int32)` would be (4,). Still meaning less values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify the dtype in the constructor.

```
b = np.array(a, dtype=int)
```

Also, starting 1.24.0, `np.int` and similar are deprecated. Just use `int`.

---

Changing the pointer type is dangerous, as the memory remains contiguous, yet the actual data takes up less space. You can do stride tricks for that, but why bother [there are reasons, but you didn't say anything about them]? This isn't C++, and you more often than not do want to just copy.

Comment: What is the type of `a` in your example? AFAIK, Numpy do not perform any reinterpret cast using the constructor, only safe cast which behave very differently (and the OP want a reinterpret cast from my understanding).

Comment: I want to use the same memory but in a different view (from `np.int64` to `np.int32`/`np.float32`/`np.float64`...). for example, `np.float64` 1.0 would be `np.int64` 4607182418800017408. I know what I am doing and I will be careful.  `view` is what I need.

Comment: @JérômeRichard the type is an iterable of something representing a number which can be converted to int. In the answer I explain why reinterpret is an overkill, which is a good reason not to accept it.